# Variables not accessible on switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, switch-statement

The variables `start` and `end` are not accessible inside of the other switch case. But should be.

The code

```
for (let key in filters) {
            let obj = filters[key];
            if (!filters.hasOwnProperty(key) || obj === '' || obj.length === 0) {
                continue;
            }
            let start;
            let end;
            switch (key) {
                case "datum_van": {
                    start = new Date(obj);
                    break;
                }
                case "datum_tot": {
                    end = new Date(obj);
                    break;
                }
                case "dateVal": {
                    filteredRoutes = filteredRoutes.filter(tocht => {
                        let date = this.parseJsonDate(tocht.datum_van);
                        switch (obj) {
                            case 0: return date >= start && date <= end;
                            case 1: return date >= start;
                            case 2: return date <= end;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: If it worked before and doesn't work now.... what did you change?  How is it not working?  Do you get error messages in your console?

Comment: The standalone date filter works but not implemented, that's what I am trying to figure out. with worked before I meant before implementing the date filter. The rest of it does work.

Comment: Which part of this are you referring to when you say "date filter"?  Can you be more specific?  What code was added?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the issue, it is due to `start` and `end` not being accessible on the `case "dateVal"` fixed it by putting my `let start;` and `let end;` outside of the for loop.

Like so:

```
let start;
let end;
for (let key in filters) {
...
}
```

instead of:

```
for (let key in filters) {
let start;
let end;
...
}
```